# Why pixel value stays the same?

Tags: arrays, numpy, opencv, image-processing

so, I'm trying to flood fill different regions of the image, with different shades of grey.
This is my input image:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbbbi.jpg)

So here is my code for flood filling one of the regions with some grey shade:

```
image = cv.imread('img.jpg', 0)

height, width = image.shape[:2]

for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        if image[i][j] == 255:
            cv.floodFill(image, None, (i, j), 90)
            cv.imwrite('test1.jpg', image)
            break
    else:
        continue
    break
```

After this I get:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOI1s.jpg)

And if I try to load the new image again, and go through the pixels, the same pixel that was used to start flood fill in the previous example, still has the 255 value instead of 90.
How is that? What am I missing here?

Thanks, guys!

Comment: Did you try debugging and checking if it actually enters the loop?

Comment: BTW, you know that you can just set all the white pixels to another color with `img[img==255] = 90`, right? Presumably you're doing more processing than you show here though so you can't do that...but just wanted to be sure :). Also, bravo for the proper use of `for...else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`floodFill()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gaf1f55a048f8a45bc3383586e80b1f0d0) and other functions which take a *point* expect them to be in `x, y` coordinates. You're sending in `row, col` coordinates instead (i.e., `y, x`), so you're `floodfill()`ing a different area than you actually detect that is white.

Comment: just as you said, in OpenCV `floodFill()` expects coordinates for some point in the mathematical sense of reading the coordinates. Somewhere should be noted that `floodFill()` doesn't want the CS matrix notation if you want to select an element in a 2D matrix that represents some grayscale image, it expects you to think in a way that you pair column index with the x-axis and row for the y-axis.

Comment: @Igor I think that's mostly because OpenCV is at heart a C++ library. In the C++ lib, you need to pass in a `Point` object which makes it clear that it's x, y. But since Python's bindings use numpy, you just pass an array or list in and it works---but there's no inherent order in a numpy array. So yeah just keep an eye out for inputs that take a "point". Similarly with "sizes", which are normally `rows, cols` in matrix world, but are `width, height` in OpenCV world (again, easier to remember if you're using a `Size` in C++ but opposite from an `array.size` from numpy).